# Getting HTML id tags using perl

Tags: perl

I can get html parameters like

```
name="something"
```

like this

```
cgi->param("something")
```

then what about when i want to get for id

```
id="something"
```

Comment: what you mean, i mean how can i get html id tag parameter in cgi perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser only [sends](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) the name and and value of successful controls, and the [name](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name) is set by the element's `name` attribute. Their `id` attribute is not sent, so you will need to use the correct attribute.